# create a database entity of nested objects

Tags: json, spring, postgresql

I want to create a table of Topic in postgresql database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Topic")
public class Topic implements Serializable {
@Id
@JsonProperty("id")
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name ="name")
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@Column(name ="Content")
@JsonProperty("Content")
private TopicContent content;
}

Class Content implements Serializable{
     List<Element> abc;
     List<String> xyz;
}


Class Element implements Serializable{
    String a;
    String b;
}
```

I've put JsonProperty and column annotations to the below objects too. When I save a Topic object in database from Spring boot controller, it saves Content object in a column in bytea format. Also when I fetch this row from database and assign it to a Topic object, it gives error that we cant assign this to Topic object. So, I want to be able to store the Content object in Json format in the table column and when I fetch data, I should be able to save assign this data to Topic object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AttributeConverter` to persist your data as JSON. See sample code below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Topic")
class Topic implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "content")
    @JsonProperty("content")
    @Convert(converter = ContentToJson.class)
    Content content;
}

class Content implements Serializable{
    @JsonProperty("abcs")
     List<Element> abc;
    @JsonProperty("xyzs")
     List<String> xyz;
}


class Element implements Serializable{
    @JsonProperty("a")
    String a;
    @JsonProperty("a")
    String b;
}


@Convert
class ContentToJson implements AttributeConverter<Content, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Content attribute) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attribute);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log error
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Content convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(dbData, Content.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log error
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```